# Is it possible to integrate Drools 8 with jBPM 7.73.0.Final?

Tags: drools, jbpm, kogito

Is there a way for jBPM 7.73.0.Final to work with Drools 8, or it is planned to have a jBPM version to work with Drools 8?

I am working on a EAR application that is already using Drools 8 for business rules. I would like to integrate BPM into the application.

Accordingly to Kogito supporters, Kogito is not supposed to work within an ear, or on an application server, but only on Quarkus or Spring.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to integrate jBPM 7 to work with Drools 8.

The ear modules (ejbs and wars) are using shared libraries, so I did not manage to make both Drools versions (7 and 8) to live together, without a lot changes in deployment descriptors, which is not acceptable.